# iOS: How to disable Fading in and out effect of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

First of all, sorry for the title and asking this incredibly question but I simply couldn't figure it out. Also, since it is not related to code, I don't have code to show

I am working on an app and using iOS7 and I created a button from IB, set its background image to an image I designed. Connected it with header and set its touch up inside action as an IBAction

Yet, here is my problem. Whenever I click on the button, as an effect the image fades half transparent. I do not want this default attribute. I checked all the states on IB (highlighted, disabled, selected) and couldn't figure it out.

If I create the same button programmatically, only the text color changes, however when I set the background image, image fades (perhaps to indicate the button being pressed). How can I remove this effect?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments & responses

Answer (score 42):

A bit late but I believe this would solve the problem

in the xib file, set the button's type to Custom.

My button was set to system and when pressed on, it shows transparency and has a little fade in effect. Once I changed it to custom this effect is gone.

This cannot be changed once button is created. only in xib or when the button is first created.

Answer (score 12):

have you tried this one `yourButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO`?

Comment: Yeah. It only works when I put the 'image' setting of the button. If I put it to 'background' it does not work out.

Comment: Thank you dude, I had a background button, and that little code prevented it from getting highlighted :)

Answer (score 1):

If you set same background-image/background-color for every buttons states in IB (highlight, disable, selected) you will not get any fading in UIBUtton when you press it. You can set text color for every states also. If needed you can set different colors for every state and check the press action.

Hope the answered you expect. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for at least paying attention. I've tried but it didn't work out.

Comment: Wrong, the fade-in effect is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard Solution

1:set button type to custom
2:uncheck "Highlighted adjusts Image" [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want fading in & out effect your **UIButton Type** Should be a **system**, not custom.